# SharePoint List View Indexing is not working

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint Custom List it contains  more than 5000 items. I created Indexed column before list cross the 5000 items, we are unable to see the Items on the List View once its crosses the 5000 records.

SharePoint List View giving me the following error after reaches the 5000 Items even though I have created Indexed column in SharePoint List

"This view cannot be displayed because it exceeds the list view threshold (5000 items) enforced by the administrator.

To view items, try selecting another view or creating a new view. If you do not have sufficient permissions to create views for this list, ask your administrator to modify the view so that it conforms to the list view threshold."

Answer (score 0):

The view needs to filter content based on the columns you specified as indexed. If you have a non-indexed column as a filter or the number of results you have with the correct filter exceed 5000, you will have this error

Comment: It is working only with ID column, But i have created some more index column for those columns filter view is not working if that column contains more than 5000 items. List filter on the column is also not working with the List contains more than 5000 items. its giving bellow error .                "Cannot show the value of the filter. The field may not be filterable, or the number of items returned exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator."

Comment: Are you sure the columns are indexed? a full crawl was made after you specified the indexes?

Comment: yes. I made all the column indexed before inserting the items.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing same issue but then i got one Solution,

Just remove sort from your View, then try that will solve it